# prevent "input field on-focus" & blinking caret

Tags: android, html, ipad

I have a page with different `<input type="text" name="mytextfield"/>`.
When the page loads all browsers show the caret (insertion point) in the input field.

In Android & iPad this fires the keyboard directly without the user beying able to see the page and choose wich input field to write in.

**Q:** Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: is it Ok to use javascript/jquery? If yes try .blur..

Comment: @Markipe, following your idea I tried `<input type="text" name="mytextfield" onfocus="blur()" />` which works. Is it good practise?

Comment: No, I cannot really recommend putting it on element's onfocus, but for better solution, try my answer below. It only blurs inputs, on first load. =)

Comment: Haha, I am tired, my idea makes "onfocus" impossible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, once page loads it removes on-focus to your textbox

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=text]").blur();
    });
```

For plain javascript use this

```
window.onload=function(){ 
    document.getElementsByName("mytextfield")[0].blur();
    /*other textbox*/
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

Comment: Good idea, is this jQuery? I am using mootools.

Comment: yes its in jquery, but if you want plain javasript try my updated answer.